# Filtering Multiple Combobox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

I am creating a "Voting system" and i have problem on the ballot form. 
Every time i choose candidate in my combobox, the rest of the combobox will also change.

here is my ballot form..

[image: ballot form]

and when i choose my President candidate in my combobox1 this what happens..
[image: ballot when changing combobox1]

I guess its because of my 'Candidate' table?? 
My issue here is how can i filter combobox1 like for example... listing All "president candidate on my combobox1. without affecting other comboboxes.

PLEASE HELP Im a student and my Thesis defense is on Friday ... LOL

Comment: We'll need to see the code in your `ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` event. This is likely where the problem lies. (Could also possibly be in `ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged` event)

Comment: @Sylverac these are my codes: For 'ComboBox1'.click
`Me.VoteTableAdapter.FillByPresident(Me.PositionDataSet.vote)`

Comment: @Sylverac these are my codes: For **ComboBox1**.click
`Me.VoteTableAdapter.FillByPresident(Me.PositionDataSet.vote)`

my **ComboBox2**
`Me.VoteTableAdapter.FillByVicePresident(Me.PositionDataSet.vote)`

my **ComboBox3**
`Me.VoteTableAdapter.FillBySecretary(Me.PositionDataSet.vote)`

i guess because of `Me.`Vote??? thats why the entire forms affects the filtering of combo box??